# Mongoose model testing require models

Tags: node.js, mongoose, mocha.js

I have a problem testing my mongoose models

I have a structure like

- app

  - models

    - Address
    - User
    - Organization
  - test

Both models User and Organization need to know the model Address. My models are structured like:

```
module.exports = function (mongoose, config) {

    var organizationSchema = new mongoose.Schema({

        name : {
            type : String
        },
        addresses : {
            type : [mongoose.model('Address')]
        }

    });

    var Organization = mongoose.model('Organization', organizationSchema);

    return Organization;
};
```

In my normal app i require Address before requiring User and Organization and everything is fine. I now wrote tests for User and Organization. In order to have the Address model registered i call `require('../models/Address.js')` This works fine if i run one test. But if i run all tests in a batch i get an error because i tried to register Address twice.

`OverwriteModelError: Cannot overwrite Address model once compiled.`

How do i solve this problem?

Comment: I answered a similar question here.

http://stackoverflow.com/a/16248673/383217

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The problem is that you cant set mongoose model twice. The easiest way to solve your problem is to take advantage of node.js `require` function.

Node.js caches all calls to `require` to prevent your model from initializing twice. But you wrapping your models with functions. Unwrapping them will solve your problem:

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var config = require('./config');

var organizationSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    name : {
        type : String
    },
    addresses : {
        type : [mongoose.model('Address')]
    }
});

module.exports = mongoose.model('Organization', organizationSchema);
```

Alternative solution is to make sure that each model initialized only once. For example, you can initialize all you modules before running your tests:

```
Address = require('../models/Address.js');
User = require('../models/User.js');
Organization = require('../models/Organization.js');

// run your tests using Address, User and Organization
```

Or you can add `try catch` statement to your models to handle this special case:

```
module.exports = function (mongoose, config) {

    var organizationSchema = new mongoose.Schema({

        name : {
            type : String
        },
        addresses : {
            type : [mongoose.model('Address')]
        }

    });

    try {
        mongoose.model('Organization', organizationSchema);
    } catch (error) {}

    return mongoose.model('Organization');
};
```

---

**Update:** In our project we have `/models/index.js` file to handle everything. First, it calls `mongoose.connect` to establish connection. Then it requires every model in `models` directory and creates a dictionary of it. So, when we need some model (e.g. `user`) we requires it by calling `require('/models').user`.

Comment: I would like to go with the first solution but i am worried because of the references to mongoose, i hope this doesnt brake the reference to mongoose because i do mongoose.connect in my app.js file, but as you say node will collect the requires and give a copy if it is already required?

Comment: Refactored my code, removed the function wrapper and works fine, thank you!

Comment: Yes, but in this case you should call `mongoose.connect` before initializing any of your models.

Comment: i think mongoose will buffer these actions until a connection is established?

Comment: I'm not sure about it, but it's easy to test.

Comment: i require my models before connecting to the database, as far as i can see this works

Comment: In our project we have `/models/index.js` file to handle everything. First, it calls `mongoose.connect` to establish connection. Then it requires every model in `models` directory and creates a dictionary of it. So, when we need some model (e.g. `user`) we requires it by calling `require('/models').user`.

Answer (score 3):

Best solution (IMO):

```
try {
  mongoose.model('config')
} catch (_) {
  mongoose.model('config', schema)
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This question already has an answer, but for a unique way to accomplish this check out https://github.com/fbeshears/register_models.  This sample project uses a register_models.js that includes all models from an array of file names.  It works really well and you end up with all your models pretty much wherever you need them.  Keep in mind node.js's cache will cache objects in your project while it's running.

Answer (score 0):

I use try/catch to tackle this problem and it works ok. But i think this not the best way of doing this.

```
try{
    var blog = mongoose.model('blog', Article);
} catch (error) {}
```

Answer (score -1):

I fixed this by patching r.js and making sure that all my modules used localRequire calls.

Checkout the thread here

https://github.com/jrburke/requirejs/issues/726